# Stuck on two valid squares in minesweeper How to solve?

Tags: minesweeper

The 1 indicates that ones of the two questioned flags is a mine and 3 also indicates the same. How to choose logically between any one of them?

[image: Board with two equally valid moves]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't it's 50/50 there's no way of knowing which one is safe and which one will kill you.

Flip a coin...

Comment: Why is this answer so popular all of a sudden :D I got like double the up votes in a day (not complaining!)

Comment: It's because Robotnik edited the question, so it's showing up on the front page again.

Comment: @ИвоНедев there's a hot network question that is linked as a possible duplicate of this question.